# How to show the name of a partial in the generated HTML itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, actionview

I searched but couldn't find a straightforward answer. I would like to be able to see which partial generated a certain piece of HTML. So when in a view I would say:

```
<%= render :partial => 'stackoverflow', locals: { answers: "johny be good" } %>
```

with e.g. `app/views/_stackoverflow.html.erb` containing

```
<p><%= answers %></p>
<hr>
```

that the resulting HTML would inject a html comment with the name of the rendered partial like:

```
<!-- partial: 'app/views/_stackoverflow.html.erb' -->
<p>johny be good</p>
<hr>
```

I assume there is a configuration option for this, but can't seem to find anything.

I know that the rendered partials are shown in the rails server log, but that is *not* what I am looking for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that actually answers the question. Someone closed this question, and linked it to an answer that did not answer this one. I specifically stated that I anm looking for a configuration option,which is *not* what was provided in the linked answer. What should I do? If you add you comment as an answer, I will upvote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be fair, I have to look it up every single time, because I can never remember the name for this config:
*https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-action-view-annotate-rendered-view-with-filenames*

You should already have it in *development.rb*, just uncomment it:

```rb
# config/environments/development.rb

# Annotate rendered view with file names.
config.action_view.annotate_rendered_view_with_filenames = true
```